# Артефакты при разворачивании приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Создаю приложение на WPF, в нем использую не стандартное оформление (собственные элементы управления, рамка, фон и др.). На заднем фоне имеется изображение.

При разворачивании приложения в обычное состояние происходят "артефакты", на долю секунды все приложение покрывается серыми и белыми полосами (помехами). На самом приложение это не как не отражается, все работает и отображается отлично, но полосы при разворачивании... Хм, раздражают.
В общем подскажите, в какую сторону копать и что стоит предпринять в данном случае?

---

[image: Смог запечатлеть эти "полосы"]

Comment: Ну, если вы не приведёте воспроизводящий пример, то придётся ждать совета от экстрасенсов.

Comment: @VladD Что именно Вы подразумеваете под "воспроизводящий пример"? Если само приложение, то можно скачать с [моего сайта](https://evgeniy-z.ru/files/agent/latest). Если что то другое, то напишите, постараюсь предоставить!

Comment: Ну, вы ведь не думаете, что увидев приложение без исходного кода, мы догадаемся, в чём проблема? Под воспроизводящим примером имеется в виду вот это: [mcve].

Comment: @VladD И то верно, мой просчет!
Вот собрал весь необходимый [интерфейс](https://evgeniy-z.ru/TempSource.zip)

Comment: Всё равно получается очень много. Например, у вас в `App.xaml` много стилей. Читать их все и разбираться — большая работа. Может быть, они не все нужны? У вас куча шрифтов в ресурсах — можно обойтись без них всех? Как правило, достаточно маленький пример имеет размер около 50 строк, ни в коем случае не превышает 200 строк, и помещается прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @VladD Сделал эту "большую работу". Нашел конкретно в чем проблема. Все дело в подключение файла перевода приложения. А именно в  этой строке `<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Language/lang.xaml" />` файла `App.xaml`. Но вот к сожалению не понял как на этой схеме перевода убрать данный баг...

Comment: Ну вот, видите, проблема уже частично локализована. Тогда вы можете выложить воспроизводящий пример в вопрос?

Comment: @VladD Сократил до самого минимального [вот архив](https://evgeniy-z.ru/WpfApplication1.zip)